# How to convert Cross-Domain Pinterest RSS feed into JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to write a program that takes a username as input and returns that 
user’s Pinterest RSS feed as a JSON structure. Here is what I have so far:

```
var input = prompt("Please enter a username: ");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.pinterest.com/'+input+'/feed.rss',
        dataType: 'jsonp',             
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error', data);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success', data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log('done');
        }
    });
});
```

Originally, I tried using JSON, but that ran into the Cross-Domain issue.  When I use JSONP, it returns the data as XML format.  I tried converting the XML to JSON but have been unsuccessful. Am I correct in my thinking, or should I be using a completely different approach? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Adam in the comments, Google Feed API is now deprecated.

[superfeedr.com](http://blog.superfeedr.com/google-feed-api-alternative/) is one alternative.

<s>You can use [Google Feed Api](https://developers.google.com/feed/) to do just that.</s>

Found this on google [Example](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tutorial-create-a-pinterest-feed-jquery-plugin-using-ajax-jquery-isotope/).

Comment: Using the demo, it seems like it just recreates the same pinterest feed. From there, would I be able to use getJSON to log it to console? I'm not sure if it is now a local pinterest feed.

Comment: It's an example I found on google. you have to adapt it to your needs. Google Feed already converts the RSS feed to JSON - just read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide

Comment: @user2731392 - if you want an example how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/mvark/Bg6FZ/